# Backbone undersore hitting all items in collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Yip I am a novice to backbone and underscore. First of all let me say I have read through all the online examples, but I'm still missing something.

Whats happening is I'm loading up my list of objects fine, but when I click delete its going through all the objects. I know this is because I'm not assigning the individual items correctly, but I cannot see what is causing this.

I would love some help.

Here is basic html code

```
<div id="itemid" class="view">            
      <span class="text">{{-text}}</span>
      <a id="dele" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon='delete' >Delete</a>
</div>
```

This is my itemlist code

```
bb.view.List = Backbone.View.extend(_.extend({    
  tagName: "ul",

  initialize: function( items ) {
          var self = this
      _.bindAll(self)

      self.setElement('#itemid')

      self.elem = {
         text: self.$el.find('#text')
      }
      self.items = items

  },

      render: function(items) {
      var self = this

      self.$el.empty()

      self.items.each(function(item){
          var itemview = new bb.view.Item({
              model: item
          })
          itemview.render()
      })
  }

},scrollContent))
```

Now finally the itemview for individual items, note the template code below.

```
bb.view.Item = Backbone.View.extend(_.extend({  
  tagName: "li",
  events: {
      'tap #dele': function(){ 
        var self = this
       self.removed()      
        return false;
      }  
  },  

    render: function(){
        var self = this
        _.bindAll(this)
        self.setElement('#itemid')

        self.elem = {
        dele: self.$el.find('#dele')
        }       

        var html = self.tm.item( self.model.toJSON() )
        $(this.el).append( html )  

    },

    removed: function()
    {
        var self = this
        this.model.removed();
    }
},{
    tm: {
      item: _.template( $('#itemid').html() )
    }
}))
```

Hope someone can help

mark

Comment: One big problem is that you have multiple elements with the same `id` (multiple with `itemid` and multiple with `dele`).  That's invalid, and it's a problem because your views are setting `View.el` based on those IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you helped point me in the right direction and I got it working. I was going down a different path. Need to get my head around the template options.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not directly related to your question, but I have couple suggestions re. your code:

You seem to use `var self = this; self.method()` everywhere. You do not to do this unless you need to pass `this` into a closure. But yes, you need it when you go into `each` iterator.

You do not need to call `_.bindAll(self)` on all methods. Again, you are better off explicitly binding `this` to methods, e.g.:

```
this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
this.el.on('click', 'a', this.handleClick.bind(this));
```

You probably don't realize and possibly are not even concerned about your client's resources at this point, but binding your environment to `this` creates a lot of closures (allocating memory) that you will never use.

Now with your issue, I would refactor your code as follows:

```
var itemTmp = $('#itemid').html();

bb.view.Item = Backbone.View.extend({  
    tagName: "li",

    events: {
        'tap #dele': "deleteItem"
    },

    render: function(){
        this.el = _.template(itemTmp)(this.model.toJSON());
    },

    deleteItem: function() {
        this.model.destroy(); // deletes model
        this.remove(); // deletes view
    }
});


bb.view.List = Backbone.View.extend({    
    tagName: "ul",

    initialize: function(items) {
        this.setElement('#itemid');
        this.collection = items;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this; // yes, you will need it in the iterator

        this.$el.empty();

        this.collection.each(function(model){
            var itemview = new bb.view.Item({
                model: model
            });

            itemview.render();
            self.$el.append(itemview.el);
        });
    }

});

_.extend(bb.view.List.prototype, scrollContent);
```

Note that `Item` view does not insert its HTML into DOM (or parent view element). Basically it's a better practice when sub-views or dependencies do not access parent's element. Therefore you can either have `render()` return HTML, or you can access View's instance `el` attribute from the module that instantiated it.

Last observation -- when you have an app with A LOT of views, you don't want to create new View instance for each list item. You're better off inserting DOM nodes with unique id's and then on DOM events read these ids and parse item ids, and look up items by `this.collection.get(id)`. But again, this is coming from pure performance considerations.